# Matlab calculate 3D similarity transformation. fitgeotrans for 3D

Tags: matlab, transformation, similarity, affinetransform, rotational-matrices

How can I calculate in MatLab similarity transformation between 4 points in 3D?
I can calculate transform matrix from

`T*X = Xp`,

but it will give me affine matrix due to small errors in points coordinates. How can I fit that matrix to similarity one? I need something like `fitgeotrans`, but in 3D

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by @rayryeng is correct, given that you have a set of up to `3` points in a `3-dimensional` space. If you need to transform `m` points in `n-dimensional` space (`m>n`), then you first need to add `m-n` coordinates to these `m` points such that they exist in `m-dimensional` space (i.e. the `a` matrix in @rayryeng becomes a square matrix)... Then the procedure described by @rayryeng will give you the exact transformation of points, you then just need to select only the coordinates of the transformed points in the original `n-dimensional` space.

As an example, say you want to transform the points:

```
(2 -2 2) -> (-3 5 -4)
(2 3 0) -> (3 4 4)
(-4 -2 5) -> (-4 -1 -2)
(-3 4 1) -> (4 0 5)
(5 -4 0) -> (-3 -2 -3)
```

Notice that you have `m=5` points which are `n=3`-dimensional. So you need to add coordinates to these points such that they are `n=m=5`-dimensional, and then apply the procedure described by @rayryeng.

I have implemented a function that does that (find it below). You just need to organize the points such that each of the source-points is a column in a matrix `u`, and each of the target points is a column in a matrix `v`. The matrices `u` and `v` are going to be, thus, `3` by `5` each.

**WARNING:**

- the matrix A in the function may require A LOT of memory for moderately many points `nP`, because it has `nP^4` elements.
- To overcome this, for square matrices `u` and `v`, you can simply use `T=v*inv(u)` or `T=v/u` in MATLAB notation.
- The code may run very slowly...

**In MATLAB:**

```
u = [2 2 -4 -3 5;-2 3 -2 4 -4;2 0 5 1 0]; % setting the set of source points
v = [-3 3 -4 4 -3;5 4 -1 0 -2;-4 4 -2 5 -3]; % setting the set of target points
T = findLinearTransformation(u,v); % calculating the transformation
```

You can verify that `T` is correct by:

```
I = eye(5);
uu = [u;I((3+1):5,1:5)]; % filling-up the matrix of source points so that you have 5-d points
w = T*uu; % calculating target points
w = w(1:3,1:5); % recovering the 3-d points
w - v % w should match v ... notice that the error between w and v is really small
```

The function that calculates the transformation matrix:

```
function [T,A] = findLinearTransformation(u,v)
% finds a matrix T (nP X nP) such that T * u(:,i) = v(:,i)
% u(:,i) and v(:,i) are n-dim col vectors; the amount of col vectors in u and v must match (and are equal to nP)
%
    if any(size(u) ~= size(v))
        error('findLinearTransform:u','u and v must be the same shape and size n-dim vectors');
    end
    [n,nP] = size(u); % n -> dimensionality; nP -> number of points to be transformed
    if nP > n % if the number of points to be transform exceeds the dimensionality of points
        I = eye(nP);
        u = [u;I((n+1):nP,1:nP)]; % then fill up the points to be transformed with the identity matrix
        v = [v;I((n+1):nP,1:nP)]; % as well as the transformed points
        [n,nP] = size(u);
    end
    A = zeros(nP*n,n*n);
    for k = 1:nP
        for i = ((k-1)*n+1):(k*n)
            A(i,mod((((i-1)*n+1):(i*n))-1,n*n) + 1) = u(:,k)';
        end
    end
    v = v(:);
    T = reshape(A\v, n, n).';
end
```

Answer (score 7):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, you seek to find all coefficients in a 3D transformation matrix that will best warp one point to another.  All you really have to do is put this problem into a linear system and solve.  Recall that warping one point to another in 3D is simply:

```
A*s = t
```

`s = (x,y,z)` is the source point, `t = (x',y',z')` is the target point and `A` would be the 3 x 3 transformation matrix that is formatted such that:

```
A = [a00 a01 a02]
    [a10 a11 a12] 
    [a20 a21 a22]
```

Writing out the actual system of equations of `A*s = t`, we get:

```
a00*x + a01*y + a02*z = x'
a10*x + a11*y + a12*z = y'
a20*x + a21*y + a22*z = z'
```

The coefficients in `A` are what we need to solve for.  Re-writing this in matrix form, we get:

```
[x y z 0 0 0 0 0 0]   [a00]   [x']
[0 0 0 x y z 0 0 0] * [a01] = [y']
[0 0 0 0 0 0 x y z]   [a02]   [z']
                      [a10] 
                      [a11]
                      [a12]
                      [a20]
                      [a21]
                      [a22]
```

Given that you have four points, you would simply concatenate rows of the matrix on the left side and the vector on the right

```
[x1 y1 z1 0 0 0 0 0 0]   [a00]   [x1']
[0 0 0 x1 y1 z1 0 0 0]   [a01]   [y1']
[0 0 0 0 0 0 x1 y1 z1]   [a02]   [z1']
[x2 y2 z2 0 0 0 0 0 0]   [a10]   [x2']
[0 0 0 x2 y2 z2 0 0 0]   [a11]   [y2']
[0 0 0 0 0 0 x2 y2 z2]   [a12]   [z2']
[x3 y3 z3 0 0 0 0 0 0] * [a20] = [x3']
[0 0 0 x3 y3 z3 0 0 0]   [a21]   [y3']
[0 0 0 0 0 0 x3 y3 z3]   [a22]   [z3']
[x4 y4 z4 0 0 0 0 0 0]           [x4']
[0 0 0 x4 y4 z4 0 0 0]           [y4']
[0 0 0 0 0 0 x4 y4 z4]           [z4']

          S            *   a   =   T
```

`S` would now be a matrix that contains your four source points in the format shown above, `a` is now a **vector** of the transformation coefficients in the matrix you want to solve (ordered in row-major format), and `T` would be a vector of target points in the format shown above.

To solve for the parameters, you simply have to use the `mldivide` operator or `\` in MATLAB, which will compute the least squares estimate for you.  Therefore:

```
a = S^{-1} * T
```

As such, simply build your matrix like above, then use the `\` operator to solve for your transformation parameters in your matrix.  When you're done, reshape `T` into a 3 x 3 matrix.  Therefore:

```
S = ... ; %// Enter in your source points here like above
T = ... ; %// Enter in your target points in a right hand side vector like above

a = S \ T;
similarity_matrix = reshape(a, 3, 3).';
```

With regards to your error in small perturbations of each of the co-ordinates, the more points you have the better.  Using 4 will certainly give you a solution, but it isn't enough to mitigate any errors in my opinion.

**Minor Note:** This (more or less) is what `fitgeotrans` does under the hood.  It computes the best homography given a bunch of source and target points, and determines this using least squares.

Hope this answered your question!

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. But with 4 points (I do not have more) I will find S matrix, that will not be similarity. The upper left 3x3 part of it will be not a rotation because of errors in points. I want to get S and then correct it (yes, with some non-linear methods) to matrix with nice rotation part. So I thought there should be some functions to do that.

Comment: @Zheden - You should probably add this information into your post.  Without this information, your question is misleading.  You should also add some sample data and desired outcome too.  We aren't here to guess what you want.