# How to warp an image into a trapezoidal shape in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am working with the baboon image and what I want is to obtain an image like this:

[image]

I have tried with `fitgeotrans`, `projective2d` and `affine2d` without success, maybe I don't understand correctly the behavior of these functions.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note that a [mandrill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandrill) is not a [baboon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baboon), though they are in the same family.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a warning that [`fitgeotrans`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fitgeotrans.html) is part of MATLAB R2013b and so this won't work for any versions below this.

---

The process to warp the image to a "trapezoid" is quite simple.  What you need to do is create a transformation object that takes the four corner points of the image and places them to the corresponding corners of the trapezoid that you want.  Once you find this transformation, you warp the image with this transformation object, but make sure that you specify the coordinate system so that the origin is with respect to the top-left corner of the original image.  If you don't, then the origin is with respect to the new image which will be cropped.  Once you find this warped image, we display it on an image frame with respect to the original image coordinate system.

You are using the infamous [Mandrill](http://sipi.usc.edu/database/database.php?volume=misc&image=11#top) image from the [University of Southern California's SIPI (Signal and Image Processing Institute) Image Database](http://sipi.usc.edu/) and MATLAB has this as part of the image processing toolbox.  First load the dataset and because this is an indexed image with a specified colour map, [`ind2rgb`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html) is required to convert this to a colour image.

```
%// Load in the image
load mandrill;
img = ind2rgb(X,map);
```

The Mandrill image is stored in `img`, and we get:

[image]

Now the next part is to create a transformation object to warp the four corner points of the image to the trapezoid coordinates.  [`fitgeotrans`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fitgeotrans.html) does this perfectly.  You need to specify a set of "moving points", which are the points that you **want to transform**.  In this case, these are the four corner points of the original image you want to transform.  You place this into a `4 x 2` matrix where the first column is the column / `x` coordinates and the second column is the row / `y` coordinates.  I'm going to specify the top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right coordinates respectively.  Next, you need to specify a set of "fixed points" which are the points that you would like the moving points to move to in the end.  Again, this will be in a `4 x 2` matrix and these are the coordinates of the trapezoid.  I had to fool around with the coordinates to get it right but you're more than welcome to modify this for your liking.  You also want to specify a **projective** transformation because of the sheer experienced in the trapezoid.

```
%// Create perspective transformation that warps the original 
%// image coordinates to the trapezoid
movingPoints = [1 1; size(img,2) 1; 1 size(img,1); size(img,2) size(img,1)];
fixedPoints = [180 100; 340 100; 50 300; 450 300];
tform = fitgeotrans(movingPoints, fixedPoints, 'Projective');
```

`tform` stores the transformation object.  Next, we need to create a reference coordinate system for warping our image.  We want to do this with respect to the original image coordinate system.  You can use [`imref2d`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imref2d-class.html) to do that.  The first input is the size of the image, which is the rows and columns respectively in a vector, then you specify the `x`/column limits and the `y`/row limits.  We want this to be with respect to the original image.

```
%// Create a reference coordinate system where the extent is the size of
%// the image
RA = imref2d([size(img,1) size(img,2)], [1 size(img,2)], [1 size(img,1)]);
```

`RA` stores this reference frame.  The last thing you need to do is warp the image with this new transformation object.  Use [`imwarp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html) to achieve this warping.  To use the function, you specify the image to warp, the transformation object and you want to make sure that the warping is with respect to the original image frame coordinate system, so you must specify the `'OutputView'` flag to be what was created above.

```
%// Warp the image
[out,r] = imwarp(img, tform, 'OutputView', RA);
```

`out` contains the warped image and `r` contains the coordinate system that the image is with respect to.  `r` should equal `RA` for the purposes of this questions.

Now if you want to see the image, use [`imshow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html) with this new coordinate system to finally display the image.  When you do this, you'll see the axes displayed, so turn that off:

```
%// Show the image and turn off the axes
imshow(out, r);
axis off;
```

.... and we get:

[image]

---

For your copying and pasting pleasure, here's the code in full:

```
%// Load in the image
load mandrill;
img = ind2rgb(X,map);

%// Create perspective transformation that warps the original 
%// image coordinates to the trapezoid
movingPoints = [1 1; size(img,2) 1; 1 size(img,1); size(img,2) size(img,1)];
fixedPoints = [180 100; 340 100; 50 300; 450 300];
tform = fitgeotrans(movingPoints, fixedPoints, 'Projective');

%// Create a reference coordinate system where the extent is the size of
%// the image
RA = imref2d([size(img,1) size(img,2)], [1 size(img,2)], [1 size(img,1)]);

%// Warp the image
[out,r] = imwarp(img, tform, 'OutputView', RA);

%// Show the image and turn off the axes
imshow(out, r);
axis off;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer was exactly what I wanted. I was using the correct function but I used in a wrong way. Also your explanation was very clear.  I really thank you!!

Comment: My pleasure! It just takes practice :). Good luck!

Comment: I am a hardcore geometric transformation guy,  I like to multiply those matrices, not using those easy tforms! Hehehehe.  Great answer,  a geometric transformation one was missing for the book

Comment: Mandrill? I always thought it was a baboon! :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo - Why yes it is indeed a Baboon, but the standard name to give this image is "Mandrill".... and I haven't figured out why. :S? :)

Comment: @rayryeng Perhaps it's just a confusion, as with Lenna / Lena :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo - I'd give you +10 for that comment if I could :D

Comment: @rayryeng Yeah, that Lenna / Lena stuff is crazy

Comment: @rayryeng, how to substitute `fitgeotrans` if I use a previous version of MATLAB, that is R2013a? Is there another method? How to implement it?

Comment: @SPS - Yes, use `cp2tform`.  This takes control points and makes a transformation object out of it.  You'll then need `imtransform` to warp your image.  If you don't have `cp2tform`, you'll have to estimate the homography yourself.  See here for insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26635266/matlab-calculate-3d-similarity-transformation-fitgeotrans-for-3d/26635529#26635529

Comment: @rayryeng, I followed your advise for my Simulink block. It gets an image input 1280x720 (that is with a resolution of 720x1280px) to out a deformed image (400x600px). It works as matlab code but not in simulink.

Comment: Here is the code of my MATLAB Function block in Simulink: `function B = deforma(img)
%#codegen
movingPoints = [1 1; size(img,2) 1; 1 size(img,1); size(img,2) size(img,1)];
size(img)
fixedPoints=[100 100;400 100;50 700;450 700];
coder.extrinsic('cp2tform');
coder.extrinsic('imtransform');
t_proj=cp2tform(movingPoints,fixedPoints,'projective');
B=coder.nullcopy(img);
B=imtransform(img,t_proj);` The problem is it returns an error _Size mismatch for MATLAB expression 'imtransform'. Expected = 1280x720x3 Actual = 601x401x3 Block MATLAB Function (#31) While executing: none_

Comment: I don't know Simulink.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @rayryeng I solved the relative problem. But what I don't understand is how the points of an image are managed in MATLAB. An image with 1280x720px is a matrix of dimension 720rows_x1280column so the moving points are defined as  _top_left(1,1),top_right(1,1280),bottom_right(720,1),bottom_left(720,1280)_  or _top_left(1,1),top_right(1280,1),bottom_right(1,720),bottom_left(1280,720)_ ? Is the second solution the correct one?

Comment: @rayryeng I solved the relative problem. But what I don't understand is how the points of an image are managed in MATLAB. An image with 1280x720px is a matrix of dimension 720rows_x1280column so the moving points are defined as  _top_left(1,1),top_right(1,1280),bottom_right(720,1),bottom_left(720,1280)_  or _top_left(1,1),top_right(1280,1),bottom_right(1,720),bottom_left(1280,720)_ ? Is the second solution the correct one? And could the have negative value for the fixedPoints matrix? Or the negative value becomes the 1 value point?