# MATLAB: using imwarp() vs deprecated imtransform()

Tags: matlab, image-processing

MATLAB's [`imtransform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imtransform.html) function appears to have been update/replaced with [`imwarp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html), but it's not quite the same function anymore. While `imtransform` gave the option of specifying output size (so that if, for example, you translate an image off it's canvas, it will be cropped accordingly), `imwarp` appears to have done away with a lot of those Name/Value parameters.

How can I achieve this cropping affect using `imwarp`?

Here is a runnable example using `imtransform` and the `XData` and `YData` name paramaters demonstrating the effect I'm looking for.

```
img = imread('pout.tif'); % Standard image included in MATLAB
tform = maketform('projective', [1 0 0; 0 1 0; -100 -100 1]);
[z, xdata, ydata] = imtransform(img, tform, 'XData', [1, size(img, 1)], 'YData', [1, size(img,2)]);
figure, imshow(img), title('Original');
figure, imshow(z), title('Transformed');
```

Comment: You now need to use an `imref2d` object and you specify this as an optional parameter which uses the `OutputView` option to `imwarp`.  See this post for further insight.  I transformed an image so that it has trapezoidal shape: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447767/how-to-warp-an-image-into-a-trapezoidal-shape-in-matlab/32448707#32448707

Comment: BTW, let me know if you get it working.  If you don't, I'm willing to write an answer but I figure that the post I linked is enough to solve your problem.

Comment: @rayryeng That solves the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Glad I could help. Good luck!